# Can I run mavericks on a 2015 mac

Tags: osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

Can I run mavericks on a new Yosemite macbook?  In the past I had a new mac and could not run an earlier version of MacOS on it.  Ideally I would like to make a time machine of my 2011 macbook pro with mavericks and restore it to a brand new macbook pro.  If this won't work is there a way to run mavericks as a virtual machine with the new mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macs are locked to running the version of OS X that they came with, or any later version. You cannot downgrade.

Earlier versions of OS X may not contain the device drivers and other software pieces and bug fixes necessary for running correctly on your hardware.